# If statement wont recognize string

Tags: java, string, if-statement

I have an if statement that takes a string, and if another string has the same value as that string do 1 thing, and if the variable doesnt equal that string do another thring

here is my code

```
if(Pos != "D"){
                System.out.println("doesnt = D");
            }

 if (Pos == "D" ){//WHY ISNT THIS WORKING
                System.out.println("it does = D");
                    }
```

It recognizes when the variable doesnt = D and prints "doesnt = d" but when the variable = D it does nothing. I dont know why.

thanks

Comment: it should..if the case is same

Answer (score 3):

Never compare Strings with `==` or `!=` since these check to see if two String variables refer to the same object reference, and this is not what you're interested in. Instead use the `equals(...)` or `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method to see if the two Strings have the same chars in the same order as that's what really matters here. i.e.,

Use [equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) to compare strings :

```
if ("D".equals(Pos))
```

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Why not ? Do you think I should receive a lot of reputation for knowing that ?

Comment: No, just not get used to see this kind of answer very often.

Comment: Fine, I'll throw my answer with yours and will delete mine.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I didn't ask for that

Comment: Minor exception:  If both comparands are known to be interned you can compare with `==` and `!=`.

Comment: @dystroy: is my information incorrect or misleading? If so, please delete or alter it.

Comment: @HotLicks Well, if you're sure. But that's not even an interesting optimization as String's equals does this test first.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Do you seriously suggest **you** might not know as much as me on this topic ? I was just saying I didn't want you to remove your answer.

Comment: @dystroy: yes, and why not. I'm no expert on Java, not by a long shot.

Comment: Well... you're 8k on java... I guess you know the basics...